# Qt5 paintEvent() region too small

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I wanted to implement a custom widget. When adding a `Node` object to the owning `Graph` widget by a double click, the `Node::paintEvent` happens rightfully, but the region of the `QPaintEvent` is constant and too small regardless of where I added it. The indicated bounding repaint box is always at (0,0) with width/height of (100,30).

Any Ideas why this is the case?

**Code**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QMouseEvent>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define DEBUG(lvl, x) \
    std::clog << "L" << __LINE__ << ": " << x << "\n";

class Node final : public QWidget
{
protected:
    void paintEvent (QPaintEvent * event) override {
        DEBUG(0, "Node::paintEvent");
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setBrush(QColor(127,127,127));
        painter.drawRect(posX, posY, width, height);
        auto x = event->rect();
        DEBUG(0, "PaintBox:" << x.x() << "::" << x.y() << "::" << x.width() << "::" << x.height());
    }
public:
    explicit Node (QWidget * parent = 0): QWidget(parent) {}
    int posX{0}, posY{0}, width{60}, height{60};
};

class GraphView final : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit GraphView (QWidget * parent = 0): QWidget(parent) {}
protected:
    void paintEvent (QPaintEvent *) override {
        DEBUG(0, "GraphView::paintEvent");
    }

    void mouseDoubleClickEvent (QMouseEvent * event) override {
        DEBUG(0, "mouseDoubleClickEvent");
        auto ptr = new Node(this);
        ptr->posX = event->x();
        ptr->posY = event->y();
        nodes.push_back(ptr);
        ptr->show();
    }

    void mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent * event) override {
        DEBUG(0, "mousePressEvent");
        auto ptr = static_cast<Node*>(childAt(event->pos()));
        if (ptr) {
            DEBUG(0, "FOUND X");
        }
    }
    std::vector<Node*> nodes;
};


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto* gv = new GraphView{};
    QMainWindow w;
    w.setCentralWidget(gv);
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

On a double click anywhere on the window area this is returned:

```
L34: GraphView::paintEvent
L48: mousePressEvent
L38: mouseDoubleClickEvent
L34: GraphView::paintEvent
L16: Node::paintEvent
L21: PaintBox:0::0::100::30
```

If you double click on an area between 0,0 and 100,30 the Node is displayed like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Qt has already built in a very good graph scene widget. Take a look at the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html). It is optimized for thousands of items, supports  multiple views on a single scene, zooming, shearing, rotating, etc.

---

But if you want to handle it yourself:

Coordinates in the paint event are always relative to the widgets root. So `(0,0)` is the top left corner of the widget, irrespective of where it is placed (see [coordinate systems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/coordsys.html)).

When you add a sub widget  (as your nodes) directly to a widget (as opposed to using a layout), you it is placed on the top left corner. Its size is determined by `sizeHint`.

So now, when you click e.g. at `(200,200)` you will add a new widget, and set its position members accordingly. This results in having a `Node` widget in your `GraphView` widget at `(0,0)` with size `(100,30)`. Then in the paint event, you draw a rect at `(200,200)`, which is outside the widget bounds!

You should set the geometry, so that the child widget is placed in Qt's coordinate system:

```
 void GraphView::mouseDoubleClickEvent (QMouseEvent * event) {
    auto ptr = new Node(this);
    ptr->setGeometry(event->x(), event->y(), ptr->width, ptr->height);
    nodes.push_back(ptr);
    ptr->show();
}
```

And then do your drawing `(0,0)` based:

```
void Node::paintEvent (QPaintEvent * event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setBrush(QColor(127,127,127));
    painter.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what happens if I wanted to implemented a zoom/move feature for the Graph Widget? Can I somehow move the parent coordinate system somewhere else apart from the top left?

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you use QGrahpicsScene / QGraphicsView